# How to fill an array with values in a for loop

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have to submit a script which adds two values within an for loop and puts every result in an array. I put together a script (which is not working) but I cannot figure out how to get it started.

```
#!/bin/sh

val1=$1
val2=$2
for i in 10
    do
        ${array[i]}='expr $val1+$val2'
        $val1++
    done    
echo ${array[@]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this?

```
val1=$1
val2=$2
for i in {1..10}; do
    array[i]=$(( val1 + val2 ))
    (( ++val1 ))
done    
echo "${array[@]}"
```

If you bash doesn't support `{x..y}`, use this format:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )); do
```

Also simpler form of

```
    array[i]=$(( val1 + val2 ))
    (( ++val1 ))
```

Is

```
    (( array[i] = val1 + val2, ++val1 )) ## val1++ + val2 looks dirty
```

Comment: And please let us know what grade you get after you `submit` it :-).

Answer (score 2):

[konsolebox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18698368/2698019) is right, but here are some alternatives:

```
val1=$1
val2=$2
for i in {0..9}; do
    (( array[i]=val1 + val2 + i ))
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

```
val1=$1
val2=$2
for (( i=val1 + val2; i < val1 + val2 + 10; i++ )); do
    array+=("$i")
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```